# I'm not getting the errors back using axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, try-catch

I'm not getting errors even though I have used validate() method using axios.

This is my controller,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
      $fields = $request->validate([
         'product_name' => 'required',
        'product_cost' => 'required | integer',
        'product_selling' => 'required | integer',
        'product_stock' => 'required | integer',
 ]);

Product::create([
    'name' => $fields['product_name'],
    'cost' => $fields['product_cost'],
    'selling' => $fields['product_selling'],
    'stock' => $fields['product_stock'],
]); }
```

This is my Vue file

```
    const productState = reactive({
        product_name: "",
        product_cost: "",
        product_markup: "",
        markup_type: "Markup by price",
        product_selling: "",
        product_stock: "",
        returned_errors: [],
    });

   axios .post("api/products", productState)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.response.data.errors));
```

Even if it has errors still it returns the response.

Comment: first, you should understand how `$request->validate`this throws back validation exception and its format and how laravel determines your request is an API call. You should send Accept: application/json header so laravel knows you want an API response back.

Comment: @AnujShrestha Doesn't work bro I tried :(

Comment: alright I will post an answer that works with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   try {
        $fields = $request->validate([
            'product_name' => 'required',
            'product_cost' => 'required | integer',
            'product_selling' => 'required | integer',
            'product_stock' => 'required | integer',]);
    } catch (ValidationException $ex) {
        return response()->json(['errors' =>$ex->errors()], 422); //what ever error format that you desire
    }
```

You should  `try catch` the `$request->validate` and send the custom response back, if you are sending API request.

But I don't suggest using `$request->validate`API requests you can go for Form Request or `Validator::make()` for more flexibility for api requests too and also you can catch the validation exception in the `Handler.php` file too and handle it there.

There are lots of articles already posted so try to research "Larvel Validation for API requests".
(I am not gonna link to the specific articles you can find Youtube videos Medium articles to blog posts)

It will help you to understand the Laravel validation process as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with:

```
error.response.data.error
```

or just log error and see what is the structure

Comment: But the error doesn't show

Answer (score 1):

The returned error in Axios not always has the `error.response` property. You probably should structure your error handling as [in this example in the Axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors).

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the error doesn't show